# Angular-fullstack | Yeoman - push to git with heroku failed

Tags: git, heroku, gulp, yeoman, angular-fullstack

For the purpose of a school project I need to develop a web application using Angular-fullstack generator from Yeoman.

In the process I need to push my web app with heroku. I followed all the steps but when I

```
    git push heroku master
```

I get an error message :

```
remote:        > typings install
remote:        
remote:        sh: 1: typings: not found
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-100-generic
remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_619bf0f5cc66ca8fa9680ec4149eaa76/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_619bf0f5cc66ca8fa9680ec4149eaa76/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build_619bf0f5cc66ca8fa9680ec4149eaa76/.npmrc"
remote:        npm ERR! node v6.9.1
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v4.0.3
remote:        npm ERR! file sh
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno ENOENT
remote:        npm ERR! syscall spawn
remote:        npm ERR! projet-yboo-emotion@0.0.0 postinstall: `typings install`
remote:        npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the projet-yboo-emotion@0.0.0 postinstall script 'typings install'.
remote:        npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
remote:        npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the projet-yboo-emotion package,
remote:        npm ERR! not with npm itself.
remote:        npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
remote:        npm ERR!     typings install

...

remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to ybooemotiont3m.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/ybooemotiont3m.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to   'https://git.heroku.com/ybooemotiont3m.git'
```

I don't really understand why ... I've got typings installed :

```
    typings --version
    2.0.0
```

and in my `package.json` :

```
    "dependencies": {
    ...
    "typings": "^2.0.0"
    ...
```

Comment: I don't really know about Heroku, but maybe it helps to look up ENONET. It's a standard Linux error with description `Machine is not on the network`

Comment: what angular-fullstack version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest one : generator-angular-fullstack@4.1.0

Comment: @DevManny I made some research. So running `heroku run bash` will  provide a shell environment ? However the `node`command isn't working. When a go to `/usr/local/src $ ls`it is empty. I used to type `gulp serve`to see my application on `localhost:3000`

Comment: try running locally `gulp serve:dist` and... what node version are you using locally?

Answer (score 0):

There are simple steps to follow, while pushing angular-fullstack project to heroku master for the first time.

---

These steps are with gulp tool using cmd (For Windows Machine).

1. You have to run **gulp build** from project root directory for production build.
2. Change directory from project root folder to the build folder(from cmd).
3. Initialize git repository by typing **git init** on cmd.
4. Create heroku project on heroku dashboard.
5. Type **heroku login** on cmd , if you are not logged in with heroku.
6. Add remote heroku repository by typing **heroku git:remote -a (name of your app from heroku dashboard )**. e.g **heroku git:remote -a myapp**
7. Type **git add .** for adding all the files to git.
8. Type **git commit -am "make it better"** for commit to heroku git repo.
9. Type **git push heroku master** to push the repo on heroku master.

Comment: I'll try this tonight !